# Fill List with values from a for loop in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

I'm pretty new to scala and I am not able to solve this (pretty) trivial problem.

I know I can instantiate a List with predefined values like this:

```
val myList = List(1,2)
```

I want to fill a List with all Integers from 1 to 100000 . My Goal is not to use a var for the List and use a loop to fill the list.

Is there any "functional" way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either of these will do the trick.  (If you try them in the REPL, though, be advised that it's going to try to print all <strike>million</strike> hundred thousand entries, which is generally not going to work.)

```
List.range(1,100001)
(1 to 100000).toList
```

Comment: Wow, this is easier than I thought it would be. Thanks!

Comment: `(1 to 100000)` generates numbers "on demand", the `toList` force the creation in memory of all elements. Another think that could interest you to fill collections is `Seq#tabulate`.

Comment: @shellholic: Indeed.  If you just want numbers from 1 to 1000000, you probably don't want a list.  But the OP asked for a list, so `toList` it is.

Comment: @shellholic, I thought n to m was strict and generated all the numbers? (in Scala 2.8, anyway)

Comment: @Paul - `n to m` uses immediate (as opposed to lazy) evaluation, but it doesn't actually store all `m-n+1` numbers.  If you do anything to it (e.g. map it), then every result will be stored.

Answer (score 2):

I am also very new to Scala, it's pretty awesome isn't it.

Rex has the absolutely correct answer, but as food for thought: if you want a list that is not evaluated up front (perhaps the computations involved in evaluating the items in the list is expensive, or you just want to make things lazy), you can use a [Stream](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.5/scala/Stream.html).

```
Stream.from(0,1).takeWhile(_<=100000)
```

This can be used in most situations where you'd use a List.